# Is direct sunlight okay for houseplants in Winter?

Tags: houseplants, sunlight, light

Ignoring plants that love or require direct sunlight, my understanding is that generally plants don't like it too much (leading to sunburn) and rather prefer bright indirect or filtered light. I did read though that direct sunlight is acceptable if it's only for a couple of hours a day, e.g. in the morning or evening.

Since my flat is somewhat dark but has some okay south window spots, I was wondering whether direct sunlight in Winter may be "less problematic" than direct sunlight in Summer. Spring is about to begin where I am and right now I'm measuring some 180k Lux (~16700 footcandles) of illuminance on the windowsills.

I'm mainly concerned about my new Monsteras but I also have some Alocasia, Peperomia, Rubber Tree and cuttings that could use some photons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, direct sun can be acceptable for a couple of hours and given winter you will get only a couple of hours even in a South facing window. I have kept multiple *Monstera* and *Philodendron* in a South facing window since December and I did not experienced any burning.

When it was exceptionally sunny I closed the curtains to provide some filtering. I live in Central Europe for reference.

Now as spring comes the plants are still in the window and so far so good. But I have noticed that the pots start to dry out much much faster. This is a definite sign that the plants and the pots are getting more sun light and it is time to move them back away from the window before they get burnt.